# From what game is this scene of a soldier hanging from the side of a bus?

Tags: game-identification

I came across this video today (timestamped 33 seconds in):

I think this particular scene of the soldier hanging from a bus is from a Call of Duty game or maybe a Battlefield game, but I'm not sure, and I'd like to know what game it is from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's *Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare*. The clip is for the 3rd mission "Traffic" where you have to rescue the Nigerian prime minister.

Here's a clip from YouTube:

I've marked the checkpoint where the clip you mentioned appears at.